# Ending a conv playing a media response doesn't work as expected. It pauses the audio output but doesn't quit the action

Tags: actions-on-google

Media handling with media response and exit handling with exit intents conflict somehow with users expectations. Links to the docs supplied below. Expected/actual behaviour also described.

Is there any chance to get that handled (at least in the near future) by defining custom utterances for media handling? As far as I know there is no possibility to define custom utterances/intents for "play" / "pause" / "stop" / "start over".

I set up a AoG to play streams through the [media response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses).

When I want to completely end the conversation with an [exit intent](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits) from within media response it doesn't really stop the conversation, but just pauses the player with no voice output whereas on any visual device it shows a play button instead of the pause button. On second "stop" utterance (or whatever calls the exit intent) the action finally finishes and plays the desired exit audio/shows desired text making clear that the action really *ended*.

Whereas this is somehow the expected behaviour this is still pretty annoying according user expectations. When a user says "STOP" s/he probably wants to end the conversation and not pause a stream, or am I wrong here? User case studies in our company showed that at least.

Solution would be to be able to add custom voice output when stopping media playback.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the Media response.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Prisoner.  Is there any info on when this issue will hopefully be fixed?

Comment: I don't work for Google, and they don't generally comment on when updates will be available, but I've been told they are working on the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Ending a conversation with a MediaResponse will open up player features like pause, forward, backwards and raising / lowering the volume. This is however currently broken on a Google Home device as the audio will never play. We had it working for several months until it broke and we had to switch to keeping the conversation open in order to make the audio play.

We have noticed that there are several undocumented commands which does strange things... For instance, when playing an audio with the conversation open and saying "Lämna" which is the Swedish equivalent to "Leave", the conversation will end and the audio will keep playing. The command "Stopp" will stop the audio but keep the conversation open. "Avsluta" = "End" will stop the audio and close the conversation.

None of these actions will callback to our backend and things seems to change on a weekly basis.